# how many channels can join in laravel echo server

Tags: laravel, socket.io

i have application with **laravel echo server** and have dynamic conversations channels for ex if user have 15 conversation then there will be 15 channels. 
 i made that like because i wanted to connect **webrtc** for calling system.

so my question is how many channels can a user join at a single time. if user connect multiple channels is that impact performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No major impact, but each subscription calls an auth api to authenticate user for presence & private channels. Else you can subscribe to private channel named as `chat-{user_id}` and emit all user messages to this channel along with the chat id.